# Python One line loop two functions

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

I am currently running the code below in Python. What I need to know is how I can store the value of `y` in the line `V=max(u(j) + y for y in set2)`. This line gets the maximum sum of each value for set1 and set2. In other words for the first iteration of the code, where the maximum value is 3 (1 for set1 and 2 for set2) then I would like to store the number 2 somewhere.

```
    set1=[1,2,3] 
    set2=[1,2]    
    u=lambda c: c**(1)
    for j in set1:
       V=max(u(j) + y for y in set2)
       print (V)
    else:
       V=0
```

I know one solution is to do an additional loop, I prefer to do it in one line.

Regards,

Comment: ... what is your expected output? And please don't use `lambda` that way. If you are going to *name your anonymous function* then you *shouldn't use the anonymous function syntax* and just use a normal function definition.

Comment: Thanks for the advise! The current output is 3,4,5 which is the maximum sum of each element of set1 with set2. I would like to get a tuple (3,2,1), (4,2,2), (5,2,3). that includes the sum and each element that makes up that sum.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can keep `y` along in some container (a `tuple` is the natural choice here):

```
>>> set1 = [1,2,3]
>>> set2 = [1,2]
>>> def u(c): return c**(1)
...
>>> for j in set1:
...     V, y = max((u(j) + y, y) for y in set2)
...     print(V, y)
...
3 2
4 2
5 2
```

As an aside, I have no idea what your else-clause is suppose to do, but I hope you know it is always executed, so `V` will always be 0.

Also, note that the `y` on the left-hand side of the assignment doesn't have anything to do with the `y` in the generator expression, which has it's own scope. I could have easily called it whatever I wanted:

```
>>> for j in set1:
...     V, fish = max((u(j) + y, y) for y in set2)
...     print(V, fish)
...
3 2
4 2
5 2
```